# How do I dynamically query the DB based on HTML select option?

Tags: php, html

I have a HTML drop-down list populated by querying a database. When the user chooses an option, the application should show information related to that option, **with no submit!**! That is, if I choose option `A`, automatically the application should query the DB for that info and display it.

The part of querying and displaying the data is not a problem, as it's similar to what I did for populating the list, but what I don't know is how to do this dynamically. I know how to do it using submit, but I'm not allowed to do this way for a better user experience.

As an example, suppose a hotel booking application. There are two elements, the drop-down list with dates, and a message showing the number of bookings there are for that determined date. So, upon visiting the application it may show:

```
Date: 2015/11/26             Bookings: 7
```

But now if the user changes the date, it should display the number of bookings for that new date:

```
Date: 2015/11/27             Booking: 18
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for AJAX calls.

An example of doing so with *jQuery*:

```
$("#id-of-your-select").change(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();

    $.post("php-page.php", { selectValue : val }, function(response){
        console.log(response); //handle the data pinged back by the PHP page in the variable 'response'
    });
});
```

In the PHP file `php-page.php`, you receive the data in `$_POST["selectValue"]`, and whatever you output (via `echo`, `print`, `print_r`, `var_dump`, `exit()` etc) will be received by the JavaScript/jQuery function in the variable "response".

---

References:

- [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)
- [jQuery Post](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Comment: this code should be within <script></script> within the <head> tags, right? I'm getting an  `undefined index` when echoing $_POST["selectValue"]

Answer (score 0):

Here is example of my project where i need to choose option from drop down list of Countries and based on that to query related data from database.

```
$('#ddl_country').change(function(){
        var country = $('#ddl_country :selected').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: "/admin/findDivisions",
            type: 'post', 
            dataType: 'json', 
            data: {country:country},
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){ 
                $('#ddl_division').html('<option value="0"> - Select - </option>');
                for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    $('#ddl_division').append('<option value="' + data[i]['id'] + '">' + data[i]['name'] + '</option>')
                }
            }
        }); 
    });
```

I've used ajax because i wanted to fill another drop down list with options generated from database without any reloads.

Answer (score -1):

You looking for this:

HTML + jQuery

```
<html>
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {                    
    $('#values_to_choose').change(function(){
        document.getElementById("values_to_choose").value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].text;
    });
    $("#values_to_choose").change(function(){
        var value_val = $(this).val();
        $('#values_to_be_filled').empty();
            $.post('get_values.php', {value_val:value_val}, function(result){
                if (result != 1){
                    theResult = JSON.parse(result);
                    var theLength = theResult.length;
                    var x = document.getElementById("values_to_be_filled");
                    var option = document.createElement("option");
                    option.text = "Please select ...";
                    option.value ="";
                    x.add(option);
                    for(i=0;i<theLength;i++){
                        var new_data = theResult[i].split(',');
                        var result_val = theResult[i];
                        var x =document.getElementById("values_to_be_filled");
                        var option = document.createElement("option");
                        option.value = result_val;
                        option.text = result_val;
                        x.add(option);
                        }
                }else if(result == 1){
                    alert("No value for selected option");
                }
            });
    })      
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="" name="user" id="user">
                  <input id="v1" type="hidden" name="v1"/>
                  <<select name="values_to_choose" id="values_to_choose">
                        <option value="" selected="selected">Please select ...</option>
                       <option value="1" selected="selected">Value 1</option>
                       <option value="2" selected="selected">Value 2</option>

                 <<select name="values_to_be_filled" id="values_to_be_filled">
                     <option value="">Please select ...</option>
                  </select>
 </form>            
</body>
</html>
```

PhP Script for data...

```
<?php
require_once('DB Connection');
if($_POST['value_val'] != ""){
    $get_value = $_POST['value_val'];
}
$get_results = mysql_query("select values_for_chosen_option from table where column_name  ='$get_value'") or die(mysql_error());
        $get_rows = mysql_num_rows($get_results);
        if ($get_rows > 0){
            $check=0;
            $items=array();

            while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($get_results)){
                $data = $row['values_for_chosen_option'];
                array_push($items,$data);
            }   
        }else{
            $check=1;
        }

        if ($check==0){
            echo json_encode($items);
        }
        else{
            echo "1";
        }
?>
```

Comment: I don't know if this even answers the question but you should always have an explanation of your code. (Not worth editing now due to question being closed)